# Solr 5.x.x - Passing credentials for a web crawl using bin/post?

Tags: authentication, solr, lucene, web-crawler

I have a local instance of `Solr 5.4.0` running, and I am attempting to crawl an HTTPS site which requires authentication using `bin/post`.

```
bin/post -c gettingstarted https://somesecureurl.com -recursive 2 -delay 1
```

I would like to pass my credentials with this request, but I cannot find any documentation for doing so. Is this possible? I have reviewed the following documentation:

- http://lucene.apache.org/solr/quickstart.html
- https://lucidworks.com/blog/2015/08/04/solr-5-new-binpost-utility/
- https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Post+Tool
- `bin/post -h`

If it is not possible, can someone propose an alternate solution?

Comment: Any help on this? I am looking for the same solution.

Comment: @HVT7 So far, no. You may need to dig into Nutch for this.